# Can you add a horizontal ScrollBar to a TabBar in QML?

Tags: qml

I know that TabBar is Flickable, but I would like a Scrollbar to be present to indicate this... As much as I try, I can't seem to get it working (it just crashes when I try to use the Scroll Bar).

```
TabBar {
    id: testTabBar
    width: parent.width

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
        parent: testTabBar
        anchors.top: testTabBar.bottom
        anchors.left: testTabBar.left
        anchors.right: testTabBar.right
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
    }

    Repeater {
        model: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]

        TabButton {
            required property string modelData;
            text: modelData
            width: Math.max(100, testTabBar.width / 3)
            onClicked: function() {
                console.log(modelData + " Clicked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround is if you replace TabBar+Repeater with ListView, you'll get your TabButton with support for a ScrollBar:

```
    ListView {
        id: testTabBar
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        height: contentItem.children[0].height + 20
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            height: 20
        }
        model: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]
        delegate: TabButton {
            required property string modelData;
            text: modelData
            width: Math.max(100, testTabBar.width / 3)
            onClicked: function() {
                console.log(modelData + " Clicked");
            }
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACkHicXVHBTsMwDL33K6yeOjGFbgMO5QTjABIIJhCXaYfQmtZampTU1TZQ/52UjaydTy/vxfaTH5WVsQwLXjSUrgMaPMXcaLZG1cGLzBF+AnBVoMzQJvBINb8Tbg50V5QlwFjzm/y4ldbTxhJqlkxGH9vEvaO/3Xyp/McCKS84gdTRruOBsRRpQSqzqJfxSux1OINp7HteU2dQuXWi8AOTI9tz11VlFKW7ni5u1Ebu6mc9+PZvpLen9ag0GboVy7DzB5NwDHs09Wjm0YVHlx5dhSs/y03CXDIm0N2sYTb6xLHFr4YsZlBZU6HlHdRsSed7G3eS5fXgP+PWGffiQNtQxkUCT5ILUcptNInjcS8w8afDOcxGgzaj5+5qa3TpfjY67XKMRic2u3Kx1UahUCaPvAGXVgiH/nA09NqeXLcN2l94VbiB)

Comment: That worked! Just annoying that it can't be done directly in a TabBar.